# Оповещение о вопросах с избранными метками

Tags: обсуждение, избранные-метки

Есть ли такой функционал, который позволяет в Tree, в браузере и т.д. оповестить о том, что появился вопрос, который попадает в избранные пользователем метку?

Если нету, может предложить в будущем добавить такой функционал?

p.s. может кто-то уже написал какой-нибудь плагин. которой с помощью API уже выполняет такой функционал.

p.p.s также можно сделать оповещение для комментариев и ответов.

Comment: См. также: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/77/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-e-mail

Comment: rss вроде был же (кликнуть на метку, промотать до самого низа)

Comment: про моментальное - из коробки вроде нет, но какой-нибудь юзерскрипт существует, инфа 100

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму мобильное приложение мгновенно оповещает. но хотелось бы и на компе такой функционал получить.

Comment: @SeniorAutomator мобильное приложение мгновенно оповещает вас о новых вопросах по метке?

Comment: Тут есть инструкция по подписке через RSS: [Как отслеживать обновления на Stack Overflow?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3187/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-stack-overflow)

Comment: RSS для избранных тегов тоже нет. В целом, у меня тэгов и вопросов по ним не так уж много, чтобы было проблемой раз в пару дней посмотреть.

Comment: В RSS нужно каждую метку отдельно. Да и это вообще отдельный механизм. Хорошо бы иметь страницу аналогично http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions, но только с избранными метками

Comment: Я использую [фильтры](http://stackexchange.com/filters/new) и открываю SO через закладку, которая ведет на страницу с отфильтрованными вопросами по интересующим меня меткам. Уведомления в браузере фильтры не предоставляют, но это хотя бы кастомный фид.